# Windows CE 6.0 replace memcpy Cortex A8

Tags: windows, arm, windows-ce, memcpy, neon

I'm working with the Freescale i.Mx51 and want to replace the Windows CE 6.0 memcpy function with a NEON based memcpy function.

I've found on the ARM Homepage (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html) some code how it should work.

My first problem is: Where can I found the memcpy code in my platformbuilder project and how can I change the code? I found a Tutorial (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2007/01/15/replacing-a-coredll-component-in-yamazaki.aspx) to replace showerr in the coredll but the Page is to old and there are no Screenshots anymore.

I tried to do the same with memcpy but I got stuck without all screenshots.

The second problem is: Did I have to do some more stuff to copy some data or is these assembler code enough:

```
NEONCopyPLD
      PLD [r1, #0xC0]
      VLDM r1!,{d0-d7}
      VSTM r0!,{d0-d7}
      SUBS r2,r2,#0x40
      BGE NEONCopyPLD
```

Maybe someone has done the same before or knows how to change the memcpy code.

Best Regards
Jens

Comment: On the latter point, try using that code to `memcpy` 17 bytes into a buffer on the stack and see what happens... ;)

Comment: my NEON memcpy is 344 lines long :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will most probably crash due to alignment faults.

You should use vld1.8 and vst1.8 instead to avoid this.

Further, you should check the size and the alignment conditions at the beginning and branch to sections individually optimized.

Last but not least, align the destination to 64bytes and copy 64bytes per iteration for maximum data throughput.

It isn't NEON that you need the knowledge in, but the control flow via ARM and the cache behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to replace it by rebuilding your own version of coredll, but this is tricky and requires a good knowledge of the build system. You should also consider that CE 6 does not save NEON registers on context switches by default, this will require some additional support in the BSP.
Maybe explaining why you want to iper-optimize memcpy on Windows CE may lead to someone suggesting a better solution.

Comment: Yeah I got stuck on this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2007/01/15/replacing-a-coredll-component-in-yamazaki.aspx on the point "The commands we want to execute are simple – we want to set up the local environment, change to the directory where our new “showerr” library source is, and execute a clean build.  These steps are accomplished using the commands we put into our batch file:" cause there is no screenshot with the informations.

We are blitting alot stuff and hope that it will speed up our system.

Comment: To speed-up blitting on your system you need to optimize your display driver, not memcpy. It's not granted that the display driver used memcpy at all. If it's your own code that uses memcpy to implement blitting, then it will be easier to change it there. Changing the behaviour of this function may impact other part of the system with alignment issues etc. And, as I told you in my previous post, CE6 does not save NEON registers on context switches.